# Retrieving the first entity out of several ones

Tags: json, stream, jq

I am a rank beginner with `jq`, and I've been going through the tutorial, but I think there is a conceptual difference I don't understand. A common problem I encounter is that a large JSON file will contain many objects, each of which is quite big, and I'd like to view the first complete object, to see which fields exist, what types, how much nesting, etc.

In the [tutorial](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/), they do this:

```
# We can use jq to extract just the first commit.
$ curl 'https://api.github.com/repos/stedolan/jq/commits?per_page=5' | jq '.[0]'
```

Here is an example with one object - here, I'd like to return the whole array (just like `my_array=['foo']; my_array[0]` would return `foo` in Python).

```
wget https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/8863.json
```

I can access and pretty-print the whole thing with `.`

```
$ cat 8863.json | jq '.'
$
{
  "by": "dhouston",
  "descendants": 71,
  "id": 8863,
  "kids": [
    9224,
     ...
    8876
  ],
  "score": 104,
  "time": 1175714200,
  "title": "My YC app: Dropbox - Throw away your USB drive",
  "type": "story",
  "url": "http://www.getdropbox.com/u/2/screencast.html"
}
```

But trying to get the first element fails:

```
$ cat 8863.json| jq '.[0]' 
$ jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot index object with number
```

I get the same error `jq '.[0]' 8863.json`, but strangely `echo 8863.json | jq '.[0]'` gives me `parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 0`. What is the difference? Also, is this not the correct way to get the zeroth member of the JSON?

I've looked at other SO posts with this error message and at the manual, but I'm still confused. I think of the file as an *array* of JSON objects, and I'd like to get the first. But it looks like `jq` works with something called a "stream", and does operations on all of it (say, return one given field from every object).

### Clarification:

Let's say I have 2 objects in my JSON:

```
{
  "by": "pg",
  "id": 160705,
  "poll": 160704,
  "score": 335,
  "text": "Yes, ban them; I'm tired of seeing Valleywag stories on News.YC.",
  "time": 1207886576,
  "type": "pollopt"
}
{
  "by": "dpapathanasiou",
  "id": 16070,
  "kids": [
    16078
  ],
  "parent": 16069,
  "text": "Dividends don't mean that much: Microsoft in its dominant years (when they had 40%-plus margins and were raking in the cash) never paid a dividend (they did so only recently).",
  "time": 1177355133,
  "type": "comment"
}
```

How would I get the entire first object (lines 1-9) with `jq`?

Comment: 1. The `wget` command you've specified returns a single object, so `jq .` will format it neatly.  2. Your "Clarification" is really a second question. It deals not with a single JSON object, but a stream of JSON objects.  3. A stream of more than one JSON entity is not itself a JSON entity.  For the sake of others who happen across your question, it would be good if you could reword it so that it conforms a bit more with standard terminology. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I've edited the question in a way that I hope answers your questions. I used a single-object example, but didn't think it mattered. I think there's a conceptual issue here about how `jq` works which could be helpful for others in future.

Comment: @JoshFriedlander, you also might like [tag:jtc] (I'm the developer) - a new and _alternative_ JSON processing unix utility allowing walking any JSON tree easily - just for your consideration. (btw, in `jtc` it's possible to index object children with numerical offsets).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Cannot index object with number

This error message says it all, you can't index objects with numbers. If you want to get the value of `by` field, you need to do

```
jq '.by' file
```

---

Wrt

> `echo 8863.json | jq '.[0]'` gives me `parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 0.`

It's normal since you didn't specify -R/--raw-input flag, and so jq sees the shell string `8863.json` as a JSON string, and one cannot apply array indexing to JSON strings. (To get the first character as a string, you'd write `.[0:1]`.)

---

If your input file consists of several separate entities, to get the first one:

```
jq -n 'input' file
```

or,

```
jq -n 'first(inputs)' file
```

To get nth (let's say 5th for example):

```
jq -n 'nth(5; inputs)' file
```

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. But is there no way to access just the first element? Like all fields from the first object. (In this case there is only one). It seems like that's what the tutorial does.

Comment: I mean the first object then

Comment: OK, I've added a bit to make it clearer, hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

> a large JSON file will contain many objects, each of which is quite big, and I'd like to view the first complete object, to see which fields exist, what types, how much nesting, etc.

As implied in @OguzIsmail's response, there are important differences between:

```
- a JSON file (i.e, a file containing exactly one JSON entity);
- a file containing a sequence (i.e., stream) of JSON entities; 
- a file containing an array of JSON entities.
```

In the first two cases, you can write `jq -n input` to select the first entity, and in the case of an array of entities, `jq .[0]` will suffice.

(In JSON-speak, a "JSON object" is a kind of dictionary, and is not to be confused with JSON entities in general.)

If you have a bunch of JSON objects (whether as a stream or array or whatever), just looking at the first often doesn't really give an accurate picture of all them.  For getting a bird's eye view of a bunch of objects, using a "schema inference engine" is often the way to go.  For this purpose, you might like to consider my `schema.jq` schema inference engine.  It's usually very simple to use but of course how you use it will depend on whether you have a stream or array of JSON entities. For basic details, see https://gist.github.com/pkoppstein/a5abb4ebef3b0f72a6ed; for related topics (e.g. verification), see the entry for JESS at https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Modules

Please note that `schema.jq` infers a structural schema that mirrors the entities under consideration.  Such structural schemas have little in common with `JSON Schema` schemas, which you might also like to consider.

Comment: Aha. So that's the key point missing from the tutorial: `curl`ing the Github API returns an **array** of JSON objects, while I was dealing with a sequence of them. I missed the outer brackets.

Comment: And your point about not inferring the schema from just the first is well-taken, I will look into that. Thanks for your help!